# Why tomcat's -D parameter not accepted in applicationContext.xml?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, applicationcontext

There are two war files in tomcat's webapp directory. Passing -DAPP_NAME=XYZ as VM parameter.

And trying to read the value in applicationContext.xml with syntax ${APP_NAME}.

One webapp substituting the value and the other not.

Comment: One of your webapps is likely configured with Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with `SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE` set and the other one is likely not. Are you able to post your Spring config for both webapps?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using syntax ${APP_NAME} I used

```
 #{ systemProperties['APP_NAME'] }
```

and it is working in both the webapps.

There is one difference between two webapps, that is spring-version.

```
    3.1.0.RELEASE
    3.1.1.RELEASE
```

This syntax ${APP_NAME} is working in webapp with 3.1.1 version. Though upgrading the other app to 3.1.1 version made no difference.